# How to handle human posture coordinates for sequence generation in machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, sequence

I have a dataset containing the coordinates of human posture for sake of simplicity presume this is the sample data

```
-----------------------------------
| f1    | f2     | f3    | f4     |
-----------------------------------
| [1 2] | [2 3 ] | [1 2] | [2 3 ] |
| [1 2] | [2 3 ] | [1 2] | [2 3 ] |
| [1 2] | [2 3 ] | [1 2] | [2 3 ] |
```

**What is the best way of handling these cartesian coordinates for sequence generation, so I can get the final output as cartesian coordinates?**

The methods I tried-

#### L2 Normalization

I perform L2 normalisation on the data and transform it into a vector `[f1(x) f1(y) f2(x) ...]`

After feeding it through a RNN I get the output but there is no way to undo the Normalisation and hence I cannot get the cartesian coordinates

#### Feature Engineering

I perform feature engineering and for a set (x,y) get r and theta where r is the root of the squares of x and y, and theta = arctan(y/x). Again I am. not able to get the cartesian coordinates after performing sequence generation

Answer (score 0):

Feature Engineering was the correct method, I just did not realise I could convert it back into cartesian coordinates.

For anyone else, this is how you can convert the values Cartesian->Polar->Cartesian

Let the coordinate be:

`['311.67422784', '966.54288455']`

We first define our transformation functions

```py
import numpy as np
def transformPolar(coord):
  x = coord[0]
  y = coord[1]

  r = (float(x)**2 + float(y)**2)**0.5
  theta = np.arctan(float(y)/float(x))
  return r, theta

def transformCartesian(r,theta):
  x = r*np.cos(theta)
  y = r*np.sin(theta)
  return x,y
```

```py
r, t = transformPolar(e)
print(r, t)

x, y = transformCartesian(r, t)
print(x, y)
```

```py
1015.5520528135892 1.2588608505806973
311.67422784 966.54288455
```